# In AWS lambda, what is the best way to Extract, Transform, Aggregate, and Write to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to get a 2nd option for which AWS services to use in my following use case:

1. Client calls a lambda function and writes an `Invoice` record into DynamoDB (`InvoiceTbl`)
2. In the `Invoice`, there is a collection of `bills` stored as a json attribute - `[{bill1, bill2, bill3}]` - which I would like to split up and write them individually into `BillTbl`, **only if** the `Invoice's` status is marked as **Paid**
3. And if the `Invoice` is **Paid**, I will also like to aggregate the amount and updates it to `InvoiceTotalTbl`

Of course, the straight-forward way will be doing them in the lambda function. However, I would like to de-couple `2 and 3` into another process. I'm thinking of:

## Design 1

1. Use `DynamoDB Stream` on `InvoiceTbl` to trigger another lambda function
2. In that lambda function, check if the `Invoice` status is **Paid**, then do `2 and 3`

---

## Design 2

1. In the lambda function, if the `Invoice` status is **Paid**, add it to `SQS`
2. The `SQS` will then invoke a lambda function to do `2 and 3`

#### Cons

`SQS` has a payload limit of 256 KB

---

## Design 3

1. Use `Step Function`
2. Once the `Invoice` status transit to **Paid**, it will do `2 and 3`

#### Cons

`Step Function` is expensive (cost-wise)

---

**Design 1** seems to be fine in terms of speed - `2 and 3` gets to execute quickly without much delays. But I don't like the idea that it gets trigger everytimes; `2 and 3` should only be triggered if the `Invoice` status is **Paid**, and I'm afraid over time, the cost will be expensive

Is there any other better design/aws services I should be looking at for my particular use case?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are only looking for "fast and cost-effective" then keeping it all in the same Lambda function is going to be the way to go. Everything is a trade-off, there is not one "best" way to do something here, as is true for almost everything in programming (and in life). You can't have the perfectly decoupled system and also the most cost-effective system at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't be asking for the 'magic bean'. What I'm mean is more on a 2nd opinion on the design paradigm for my use case.

Comment: For this scenario Design 1 would be my vote, as you're already decoupling (code-wise) anyway, you're just triggering them in the same lambda (will give you cost and speed effectiveness).  I'm not sure I understand that it gets trigger every time (2 & 3), 2 and 3 shouldn't trigger every time with a simple check for status Paid right?  The difference here is you're breaking down logic and flow across multiple services.  How small/fine grain of breaking things down and decouple them do you go?  Also take into consideration of debugging, deployment and maintenance cost across multiple services.

Comment: @noobius . My `Invoice` has a **Draft** and **Paid** status. Whenever user save the Invoice, the Stream lambda will always have to check if the Status is **Paid**, then proceed with `2 and 3`.  Out of 10 the save to my InvoiceTbl, 9 times will be in **Draft** status and only 1 time it will be in **Paid** status where the Stream lambda will then have to proceed with `2 & 3`. In another words, there will be 10 Stream read, but only 1 Stream read will be doing the actual work (`2 & 3`)

Comment: i will choose the design 1. You will have a unique component dynamodb managing both the storage and the lambda triggering which will reduce the complexity of your architecture. and you will have less limitation on the entry size since it's 400kb of data per item on dynamo which is 256kb on SQS. You will also have the advantage to send higher batch size from lambda to dynamo (16mb) than with SQS